# Proof that every finite number of subspaces with the same dimension of $\mathbb R^n$ have a common complement

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question is as follows:

Let there be a number of $m$ subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ that all have the same dimension.
Prove that all of these subspaces have a common complement.

I'm a little bit stuck on this question.

The cases where the dimension of the subspaces is equal to $n$ or the union of the subspaces is a subspace itself is trivial.
But apart from that I'm not sure on how to move on.
Any suggestions?

Sorry for bad English and formatting; it's my first question and not in my first language.

Comment: @copper They do have a common complement, in the direct sum sense. Of course it's not the orthogonal complement.

Comment: @MattSamuel; Thanks, I was stuck in my Hilbertian mindset...

Comment: I guess you need them to be proper subspaces right

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof by induction:

Let $d$ be the dimension of the subspaces.

Since $\mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}^n + \{0\}$ we see that the cases $d=0,d=n$ are straightforward.

Suppose $0<d<n$ and $S_1,...,S_d$ are the subspaces. Pick a point $x_{d+1}$ that is not in any of the subspaces. Then $S_k+\operatorname{sp}\{x_{d+1}\}$ are a collection of distinct subspaces of dimension $d+1$.

If $d+1=n$ then $\operatorname{sp} \{x_{d+1}\}$ is a complement, otherwise repeat the process with the $d+1$ dimensional subspaces.

This will result in a collection of points $x_{d+1},...,x_n$ such that
$\mathbb{R}^n = S_k + \operatorname{sp}\{x_{d+1},...,x_n\}$.

Comment: Why is it possible to choose some $x_{d+1} $ outside all $S_i$?

Comment: @JensSchwaiger: The cheap answer is that subspaces have measure zero, so their union has measure zero. Let me see i I can come up with a more constructive answer.

Comment: See http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-vector-space-written-as-finite-union-of-proper-subspaces/ for example.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger: Thanks!